# Morning Wood and Semen

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, salat, ramadan, ghusl

When I wake up I often find myself having an erection without any sexual thoughts which I found normal among people my age. However, When I first go to use the bathroom after the election I find a sticky liquid comes out after urination, which I believe to be semen from the erection. Do I need to perform ghusl?

Answer (score 1):

If you be sure that It's  semen [manee],  you should perform ghusl. Otherwise you should perform wudu. If the liquid be madhee [light, sticky arousal discharge ] or wadee [ thick white non arousal discharge ].